# Prove a variant of Turan's theorem.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, upper-lower-bounds

Let $m,n\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $m<n$.Prove that if $G=(V,E)$ is a graph with $|V|=n$ without $m+1$ clique then $|E|\leq \frac{m-1}{m}n^2$.

**Proof**

Since the $G$ don't have $m+1$ clique then at most $G$ have a $m$ clique, it implies that
$$|E|\leq \frac{m(m-1)}{2}\iff 2 |E| \leq m(m-1)$$ since $0<m<n$ then $(\frac{n}{m})^2\geq 0$ then if we multiply both sides by $(\frac{n}{m})^2$ we get
$$ 2 |E| \left(\frac{n}{m}\right)^2\leq \frac{m-1}{m}n^2$$.

Now we claim $$|E|<2|E|\left(\frac{n}{m}\right)^2$$

Notice that $$|E|<2|E|\left(\frac{n}{m}\right)^2 \iff 2\left(\frac{n}{m}\right)^2> 1 \iff \left(\frac{n}{m}\right)^2>\frac{1}{2}$$

But since $0<m<n$ implies that $n=m+k$ for $k\geq  1$ and then
$$\left(\frac{n}{m}\right)^2=\left(\frac{m+k}{m}\right)^2=\left(1+\frac{k}{m}\right)^2>1$$

Hence our claim is true and then
$$|E|<2 |E|\left(\frac{n}{m}\right)^2\leq(\frac{m-1}{m}n^2$$ therefore
$$|E|\leq \frac{m-1}{m}n^2$$ as well.

Is my proof right?

Comment: Your first sentence is false. Consider any cycle graph $C_n$; it has no $3$-cliques, so $m=2$ here, but it's certainly not true that it contains at most $\frac{m(m-1)}{2} = 1$ edge!

Comment: Then I should prove it by induction over $m$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints.

Use induction on $n$.
Let $G'$ be obtained from the graph $G$ by removing a vertex and $m<n-1$.

Since
$$
|E(G)|\leq|E(G')|+n-1 \hbox{ and } |E(G')|\leq\frac{m-1}{m}(n-1)^2,
$$
it follows that
$$
|E(G)|\leq\frac{m-1}{m}(n-1)^2+n-1.
$$
Now try to prove that
$$
\frac{m-1}{m}(n-1)^2+n-1\leq\frac{m-1}{m}n^2
$$
provided that $m\geq2$.
Investigate the cases $m=1$ and $m=n-1$ separately.

Comment: Thanks so much for the hint, I´m gonna try do it and update the post